Unable to access terminal
I have been using dwm on my system.
I changed something in the configuration files,
and now I am not able to access the terminal screen.
It is frozen.  When I try in a tty, it asks for credentials. 
It then executes the dwm command, which I have set in my .xinitrc.
What can I do now?  I have been stuck for several hours.

Reboot, holding the SHIFT key to get to Advanced options, select Single User Mode. You'll be root. Fix your /home/userid/.xinitrc.

hmm, this could have solved this, but anyways i reinstalled arch , thanks
